# soundcloud: How can I search my playlists by name?

Tags: api, soundcloud, playlists

I have playlists with a lot of tracks so when I query for my playlists using the API (/me/playlists) I get a huge amount of data back.  This often results in 502 and 504 errors from the Soundcloud servers.  Their documentation for /playlists describe a "q" search filter that I thought would help narrow the results of my query, but it appears to be searching *all* of Soundcloud!  Is this by design?  If so, the documentation should say so.

Either way, is there a way I can do this through the API?

Comment: yes the resource /playlists is in all's soundcloud universe.

have you tried the /user/12345/playlists with the q filter? where 12345 is the User ID.

Comment: OK looks like q=<playlist_name> is correctly searching within my playlists, thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

// find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
SC.get('/playlists', {
  q: 'YOUR_SEARCH_KEYWORD'
}).then(function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
</script>
```

[Source](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search)

Comment: I'm using the Ruby API which supports /me/playlists after connecting with the client id.  I was able to query my own playlists using that endpoint + the q filter.